# choppy sound with random popping 13.04

Tags: 13.04, sound

I was hoping some one could help me figure out why my audio is popping randomly.

I just got some new speakers and it was popping previously, but I was using monitor speakers so it wasn't really noticeable.  Now I have some Bose speakers hooked up via an analog cable.

It is not the speakers because my Android phone plays audio fine.

When I open the sound settings window the popping happens at exactly the same time a third sound device is displayed very quickly and then disappears.  This keeps happening at about 30 second intervals.

Any help is appreciate.  If you need more details just let me know how to get them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im having the same problem but I found the ubuntu sound trouble shooting guide:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure

Step 1A worked for me:

> In Terminal run the following commands:
>
> ```
> killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/* ; rm -r ~/.pulse*
> ```
>
> wait ten seconds, then run this:
>
> ```
> pulseaudio -k
> ```